# DateTime converstion Fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am trying to convert Current dateTime Object to Australian standard Time.

```
 string asd = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU"));
```

This is my code. But Datetime conversion never happens as output I am getting current datetime itself.Can any one point out What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's your current output and what is expected output?

Comment: `DateTime.ToString(IFormatProvider)` method just represents your local time on your computer with specific culture formatting. I think time zone offset is `UTC + 10` there. You can try with [`UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property instead.

Comment: When you use `DateTime.Now`, that means current date time. Here you are changing current date time into Australian culture date time. Date  remains same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you get the TimeZone

```
TimeZoneInfo aus = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, aus);
```

and this is how you fix the format:

```
dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

**More Info**

Here is the list of time zone ID for Australia, in case if you are not living at east

1. Cen. Australia Standard Time
2. AUS Central Standard Time
3. E. Australia Standard Time
4. AUS Eastern Standard Time
5. Tasmania Standard Time
6. W. Australia Standard Time

Cheers